# Cannot read the token from the 'SignatureConfirmation' element..(Java-WCF)

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, spring-ws, wss4j

I have a WCF(3.5) client talking to a Java Web Service (Spring-WS, WSS4J), the client fails while recieving the response from server giving the following exception message

> Cannot read the token from the 'SignatureConfirmation' element with the 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd' namespace for BinarySecretSecurityToken, with a '' ValueType. If this element is expected to be valid, ensure that security is configured to consume tokens with the name, namespace and value type specified.

Here is my client configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="DISEndPointBehaviour">
<clientCredentials>
<clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" 
x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="shameerpartner"/>
<serviceCertificate>
<defaultCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root"
x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="dis"/>
<authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
</serviceCertificate>
</clientCredentials>
</behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
<customBinding>
<binding name="DISMutualCertificateDuplexBinding">
<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"/>
<security authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex"
includeTimestamp="true"
requireDerivedKeys="false"
messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Rsa15" 
requireSignatureConfirmation="false"
messageSecurityVersion=
"WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
</security>
<httpTransport />
</binding>
</customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
<endpoint binding="customBinding" 
bindingConfiguration="DISMutualCertificateDuplexBinding"
contract="DaDeskDataExchange" 
name="DaDeskDataExchangeSoap11_DaDeskDataExchange"
address="http://192.168.0.27:8080/disweb/1.0/spring-ws/"
behaviorConfiguration="DISEndPointBehaviour">
<identity>
<dns value="dis"/>
</identity>
<headers>
<wsse:UsernameToken
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1"
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>119136</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password
Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">R3WWGSkNtmPztaSUbiyAWOcpwTM=</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce
EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">pkJh0dN0yE8iIRe49T1bwg==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2010-08-18T10:32:23.937Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</headers>
</endpoint>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Anybody has an idea about this error ?

Thanks,

Shameer

Comment: I have a similar problem, but with SAML -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108564 - I think it's something to do with an element missing from Java's implementation that .Net doesn't have a default for.