# Problems reading authenticating a SAML assertion in .Net using WSSecurityTokenSerializer

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, x509certificate, pkcs#7, saml-2.0

I have a SAML assertion that I wish to authenticate in .Net using `WSSecurityTokenSerializer`.

I've got the key-chain and SAML XML, despite [a few issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099467).

First I get the SAML assertion from the HTTPS POST:

```
// spec says "SAMLResponse=" 
string rawSamlData = Request["SAMLResponse"];

// read the base64 encoded bytes
byte[] samlData = Convert.FromBase64String(rawSamlData);

// read back into a UTF string
string samlAssertion = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(samlData);

// get the SAML data in an XML reader
var assertionPostStream = new StringReader(samlAssertion);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(assertionPostStream);
```

Then I get the keys provided by my IdP:

```
// get the key data
byte[] certificateData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("myKeys.p7b");

// decode the keys
var cms = new SignedCms(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber);
cms.Decode(certificateData);

// we have a keychain of X509Certificate2s, we need a collection of tokens
var certificatesAsTokens =
    from X509Certificate2 cert in cms.Certificates
    select new X509SecurityToken(cert) as SecurityToken;

// get a token resolver
var tokens = new ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityToken>(
    certificatesAsTokens.ToList());
var resolver = SecurityTokenResolver.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenResolver(
    tokens, true);
```

Finally I get an error thrown here:

```
// use the WS Security stuff to parse the reader
var securityToken = WSSecurityTokenSerializer.
    DefaultInstance.ReadToken(reader, resolver) as SamlSecurityToken;
```

When calling that `ReadToken` I get the following error:

> Cannot read the token from the 'Response' element with the 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol' namespace for BinarySecretSecurityToken, with a '' ValueType. If this element is expected to be valid, ensure that security is configured to consume tokens with the name, namespace and value type specified.

My SAML XML starts with:

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ...
```

So clearly I have a `Response` element in the `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol` namespace.

Any idea what's wrong/missing here?

Comment: After days of digging (the documentation on this stuff is terrible) I think that this may be due to `WSSecurityTokenSerializer` relying on a variant of SAML 1.1 rather than SAML 2.0 - I've switched to trying to verify the signature directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126388

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are receiving a SAML2 response. Although there is support for SAML2 in .NET 4.5, there is unfortunately only support for the assertions - not the protocol itself (including the Response message).

To process the SAML2 response in .NET you have to:

1. Validate the signature on the entire response message.
2. Extract the assertion part of the message.
3. Read the token with `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken()`.
4. Validate the token with `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.DetectReplayedToken()`.
5. Validate the token with `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateConditions()`
6. Use `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.CreateClaims()` to create a claims identity.

Unfortunately most of those methods are protected, but you can subclass `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler` and get access to them.

A complete working example can be found in the [Saml2Response](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/1.0/Sustainsys.Saml2/SAML2P/Saml2Response.cs) class in the [Sustainsys.Saml2](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) project.

Comment: The token handler does call those methods if you set up the config file and use `FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845076/wif-config-issuernameregistry-vs-certificatevalidation

Comment: Actually, I see that I'm wrong about this when the signature is at the top level and not on the assertion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883166/can-wif-saml2securitytokenhandler-validate-top-level-signature

Comment: The Saml2Response class link above is giving a 404. Do you have a new path?

Comment: @BigJoe714 Thanks for noticing the broken link, it's fixed now. Then Saml2Response class has been moved to another namespace since this post was written.

Comment: The Saml2Response link is broken. Could you update the link? Should it be this one https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/master/Sustainsys.Saml2/SAML2P/Saml2Response.cs?