# Can WIF Saml2SecurityTokenHandler validate top-level signature?

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, wif, saml-2.0, claims-based-identity

See this (stripped-down) SAML 2.0 response:

```
<samlp:Response>
  <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">lkasjdflkasj</saml:Issuer>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <!--<snip>-->
  </Signature>
  <samlp:Status xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
  </samlp:Status>
  <saml:Assertion>
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">lkasjdflkasj</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:Subject>
      <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">jsmith</saml:NameID>
      <!--<snip>-->
    </saml:Subject>
    <!--<snip, but there was NOT a Signature node inside the assertion>-->
  </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

In the code below, the xml reader is set to send just the `<Assertion>` piece of the SAML 2.0 response:

```
var handlers = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;
var token = handlers.ReadToken( myXmlReader );
var identities = handlers.ValidateToken( token );
```

If the `<Signature>` node is part of the assertion, then `ValidateToken()` will verify it using config settings, e.g. `issuerNameRegistry` (example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845076/wif-config-issuernameregistry-vs-certificatevalidation)).

But if the signature is at a higher level (i.e. the whole xml is signed, not just the assertion), then we'll get an exception like:

> ID4152: The Saml2SecurityToken cannot be validated because the IssuerToken property is not set. Unsigned SAML2:Assertions cannot be validated.

Am I understanding correctly that if the `<Signature>` exists only on the overall xml response, that I cannot call `ValidateToken` and must instead revert to more general-purpose features such as [SignedXml.CheckSignature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye0db953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean with outer signature. In WS-Fed Passive there is no outer Signature. The only case that I know of outer signatures is a "Signature Insertion" attack. WIF correctly tracks that. Could you share the XML? And SignedXml is mortally dangerous, especially because of the "Signature Insertion" attacks. Don't go there without a validating parser and proper signature validation.

Comment: @paullem added sample

Comment: Oh, maybe I am beginning to understand what you are doing. Are you parsing real SAML2 messages? If so then I regret to have to tell you that WIF does not support the SAML2 *Protocol*, it only supports SAML Tokens (Assertions). You will have to write a real validating parser++. Major work. Think weeks/months depending on what you already know.  Many commercially available implementation are broken. As far as I know all Kantara certified implementations are currently OK. Do watch if the product or the .NET code was certified...... This is a mine field. BTW I need the XML, not the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, indeed you are parsing real SAML2 messages. WIF does not support that. WIF probably considers this an unsigned Assertion.

I would have to dig in with Reflector and/or the reference source.
Any way you would have to do the parsing and verification yourself. And I personally do not use SignedXml. Maybe it is possible. It has other side effects. Welcome to the mine field.

The famous reference article: https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity12/sec12-final91.pdf

Comment: This article is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of Saml2SecurityTokenHandler and override the TryResolveIssuerToken method.  If you validate the signature in an earlier step, this method can give a thumbs-up to a signature certificate that it otherwise would have no idea about.

I now have this approach working in production code.